# Move to question from chat

Tags: feature-request, questions, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chat “propagate” function?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68542/chat-propagate-function)

We have a new feature where extended use of comments is moved to chat. I'd like to propose the reverse- chat room owners should be able to move (potentially multiple) lines of chat to a new question. The question would be "asked" by the person who placed those messages into chat. If the room owner edits the messages, say to make them more coherent as a larger section, or to place pastebinned code into the question directly, for example, then this would be marked as an edit. This way, anyone can view the original question, and if the owner makes edits which are inappropriate, they can be viewed/rolled back/etc.

This is cleaner and more efficient than just flagging inappropriately-asked questions, as the results would be immediate, and it would more directly get a questioner what they need. In addition, each room can have their own policy on what questions should be moved and which should not. And finally, questions asked this way can be correctly indexed, searched for later, and the asker can gain, or lose, reputation as appropriate.

Perhaps in addition, anyone would have the ability to do the same to their own messages.

Comment: +1 For a very good idea :)

Comment: This suggestion is less specific and better stated than what it is a "duplicate" of, so maybe the other should be closed instead…